# How to understand this basic Assembly Code that seems to be adding two pointers?

Tags: assembly, mips, reverse-engineering

**Construct a C language sentence from the following MIPS instructions. 

(var f -> $s0, starting address of array A and B ->  $s6, $s7)**

---

```
addi $t0, $s6, 4        //$t0 = &A[1]
add  $t1, $s6, $0       //$t1 = &A[0]
sw   $t1, 0($t0)        //A[1] = &A[0]
lw   $t0, 0($t0)        //$t0 = &A[0]
add  $s0, $t1, $t0      //f = &A[0] + &A[0]
```

On the left are the instructions given and comments on the right are me struggling to understand.
Final answer I got is `f = &A[0] + &A[0]`, but that doesn't seem right. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I agree, that makes little sense but seems to be correct.

Comment: `lw   $t0, 0($t0)` is a memory load, not an effective address calculation.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, but the previous instruction stored an address there.

Comment: @Jester True, I guess it depends on whether the comment is explaining each instruction individually or trying to abstract higher-level meaning.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The comment on the `lw` is correct, but yes you could include a reminder of the memory location being reloaded from, like `$t0 = A[1] = &A[0]`, as well as the original meaning of that value.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for the help, the problem seemed weird from the start 'cause it doesn't even include $s7 which it mentioned. Guess it's just not a good problem

Comment: Yeah, this problem is super weird.  It might be a mistake in the book or wherever you found it.  Do note that your C expression omits the side-effect of updating memory.  Expressing that in C might require some casting (e.g. to `uintptr_t`) because you can't actually add two pointers in C.

Comment: What's this from?  There are multiple questions based on this code, because the code is so weird people assume they've read it wrong.  [What's wrong in my thinking in translating MIPS code to C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66790508) / [MIPS to C Translation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18885288) / [MIPS addi instruction to array base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10472452).  A google search for `site:stackoverflow.com addi $t0, $s6, 4` finds mostly this, it's a unique enough combo of operands.

Comment: @PeterCordes Must be from some textbook or something. I got it from a quiz in my lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're not crazy, the code really is that weird!**

Adding two pointers basically never makes sense, so this is kind of a trick question.
The equivalent C does look wrong / insane:

```
intptr_t *A = ...;  // in $s6

 A[1] = (intptr_t)&A[0];
 f = A[1] + (intptr_t)&A[0];
```

Note that signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C, so it's legal to compile it to a MIPS `add` which will trap on signed overflow.  If we'd used `uintptr_t`, the required overflow semantics would be wrapping / truncation, which `add` doesn't implement.

(Real-world C compilers for MIPS always use `addu` / `addiu`, not `add`, even for signed int, because undefined behaviour means anything is allowed, including wrapping.  It's even required if you compile with `gcc -fwrapv`.  Since MIPS is a 2's complement machine, `addu` is the same binary operation as `add`, it differs only in not trapping on signed overflow: when the inputs are the same sign but the output has a different sign from that.)

---

In terms of C that will compile back to something closer to the given asm, or at least represent every asm operations with a C temporary var:

I used [GNU C register-global variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html#Global-Register-Variables) instead of function args so the function body would be using the actual correct register (and without cluttering the asm with extra instructions to save/restore and init those registers).  So this lets me get GCC to make a block of asm that has `s` registers as inputs and outputs, instead of the normal calling convention.

```
#include <stdint.h>

register intptr_t *A  asm("s6");
// register char  *B  asm("s7");    // unused, no idea what type makes sense
register intptr_t f asm("s0");

void foo()
{
  volatile intptr_t *t0_ptr = A+1;  // volatile forces store and reload
  intptr_t t1 = (intptr_t)A;

  *t0_ptr = t1;                  //sw   $t1, 0($t0)       //A[1] = &A[0]
  intptr_t t0_int = *t0_ptr;     //lw   $t0, 0($t0)       //$t0 = &A[0]
  f = t0_int + t1;               //add  $s0, $t1, $t0     //f = &A[0] + &A[0]
  //return f;
}
```

Note that `$t0` gets used for 2 different things here, with different types: one being a pointer into the array, and the other a value from the array.  I expressed this with two different C variables, because that's how things normally go.  (Compilers will reuse the same register for a different variable when one is "dead" before / as the other one is needed.)

The resulting asm from GCC5.4 for MIPS, with [options to make MARS-compatible asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175450/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-to-convert-c-to-mips/63386888#63386888): `-O2 -march=mips3 -fno-delayed-branch`.  MIPS3 means no load delay slots, like the code in the question which uses the `lw` result in the instruction after the load.  ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0Aregister+intptr_t+*A++asm(%22s6%22)%3B%0A//+register+char++*B++asm(%22s7%22)%3B++++//+unused%0Aregister+intptr_t+f+asm(%22s0%22)%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++//volatile+register+int+*t0+asm(%22t0%22)+%3D+A%2B1%3B++//+try+to+force+GCC+to+do+the+temp+regs+with+local+register+asm%0A++volatile+intptr_t+*t0_ptr+%3D+A%2B1%3B++//+force+store+and+reload%0A++intptr_t+t1+%3D+(intptr_t)A%3B%0A%0A++*t0_ptr+%3D+t1%3B++++++++++++++++++//sw+++$t1,+0($t0)+++++++//A%5B1%5D+%3D+%26A%5B0%5D%0A++intptr_t+t0_int+%3D+*t0_ptr%3B+++++//lw+++$t0,+0($t0)+++++++//$t0+%3D+%26A%5B0%5D%0A++f+%3D+t0_int+%2B+t1%3B+++++++++++++++//add++$s0,+$t1,+$t0+++++//f+%3D+%26A%5B0%5D+%2B+%26A%5B0%5D%0A++//return+f%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+bar()+%7B%0A++A%5B1%5D+%3D+%26A%5B0%5D%3B%0A++f+%3D+A%5B1%5D+%2B+(intptr_t)%26A%5B0%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Aintptr_t+some_array%5B10%5D%3B%0Avoid+init()%7B%0A++++A+%3D+some_array%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:71.74571140262361,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+MIPS+gcc+5.4+(el)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:28.254288597376387,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cmips5el,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-march%3Dmips3+-std%3Dgnu99+-fomit-frame-pointer+-fno-delayed-branch%27,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27MIPS+gcc+5.4+(el)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

```
foo:
        move    $2,$22         # $v0, $s6   pointless copy into $v0
        sw      $22,4($2)      # A[1] = A
        lw      $3,4($22)      # v1 = A[1]
        addu    $16,$22,$3     # $s6 = (intptr_t)A + A[1]
        j       $31
        nop                                  # branch-delay slot
```

(GCC uses numeric register names, not the ABI names like `$s?` for call-preserved, `$t?` for call-clobbered scratch regs, etc.  http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html has a table.)

Another way to write it, with less rigour:  the important difference is the lack of `volatile` to force the compiler to reload.

```
void bar() {
  A[1] = &A[0];
  f = A[1] + (intptr_t)&A[0];
}
```

```
bar:
        move    $2,$22          # still a useless copy
        sw      $22,4($2)
        sll     $16,$22,1       # 2 * (intptr_t)A;   no reload, just CSE the store value.
        j       $31
        nop
```

---

**Of course there would be other ways to express this, e.g. using `A` as an array of pointers instead of an array of `intptr_t`, `int`, or `int32_t`.**

I chose integers because C pointer types magically scale by the type width when you do pointer addition.